# Machine learning algorithms for numerical sequences of variable length

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on a machine learning project at the moment, and my problem is that I have sequences of varying length as input and would like a numerical sequence of the same length as output. Are there machine learning algorithms that can be used for these kinds of problems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually in such cases you bring all your input sequences (which are more commonly called feature vectors) to the same size. Now, how you do it depends on the nature of your data.

One simplest approach would be to just append `0` to all but longest vector. Or the opposite - trim all but the smallest vector.

When all your feature vectors are of the same size you can proceed with any machine learning algorithm out there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs).

A famous kind of these networks are LSTM that can be easily implemented using TensorFlow.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/recurrent/index.html